# logout when the browser close, onunload javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How we call logout servlet on browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986430/how-we-call-logout-servlet-on-browser-close-event)

I want my site to automatically logout user when the browser closes. I use onunload in javascript. Now, my problem is it always logout the user everytime the user navigates to other page. What I want is just to logout when the browser closes.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
window.onunload = logout;

function confirmExit() {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
}

function logout() {
    window.location = '<?php echo WEBSITE_URL ?>?logout=true';
}

</script>
```

Hope someone will help me ASAP!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How we call logout servlet on browser close event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986430/how-we-call-logout-servlet-on-browser-close-event) and also of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768281/detecting-user-logout-on-browser-close-in-django) and of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515416/automatic-log-out-when-browser-closes) and of many others. Please make use of the search facility before asking a question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66314375/5729064

Answer (score 1):

In your case its better to send a **ajax request** to do the task  rather then redirecting the user to logout.

Also send it on `onbeforeunload`

Or a better idea will be add a `cookie` with **user last activity**. and check on every page load the if the last activity is more then the required limit server redirect to the login page clearing the session.

Comment: onbeforeunload you would need to send an sjax request, btw.

Comment: To be complete, a cookie's not a safe way to handle the lifetime of your session as it can be modified by the client.

Comment: @Anzeo: Unless it's signed by the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to detect in javascript when the window is closed. As you've found out `onunload` event doesn't have the information *why* the page is unloaded: if the user closes the window or navigates to a different page.

What is more, the user may navigate to a different page by typing the url in the address bar - you might want to 'log him out' in that case too.

The best way to achieve it is to have a timeout on your session. This will work event if the browser crashes.